# How do I keep my the content on my webpage present after submission?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

My document for content is a php document (contact.php). I have a form submission to email. However,  I am not knowledgable in php. I have the form on the intial webpage, however, after submitting an invalid error, I get the text that I want, but the form, button, text and footer all disppear. How do I keep it on the new webpages after submission? Basically have it loop for each invalid submission, always allowing the user to try to correct the errors.

Here is my code for both html and php on a php document:

```
<h2>Contact</h2>
        
        
        <div id="red-error">
        
            <?php

                if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {

                // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
                $email_to = "ArthurielBoston@gmail.com";
                $email_subject = "Actor Portfolio: email submission";

                function problem($error)
                {
                    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
                    echo "These errors appear below.<br><br>";
                    echo $error . "<br><br>";
                    die();
                }

                // validation expected data exists
                if (
                !isset($_POST['Name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
                !isset($_POST['Message'])
                ) {
                    problem('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
                  }

                $name = $_POST['Name']; // required
                $email = $_POST['Email']; // required
                $message = $_POST['Message']; // required

                $error_message = "";
                $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

                if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
                }

                $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

                if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
                $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';  
                }

                if (strlen($message) < 2) {
                $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br>';
                }

                if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
                problem($error_message);
                }

                $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

                function clean_string($string)
                {
                    $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
                    return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
                }

                    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
                    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
                    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";

                    // create email headers
                    $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
 
                function valid_user_data() { 
                    // validate $_POST data 
                    // ... 
                return TRUE; 
                } 
 
                if(valid_user_data()) { 
                header('Location: https://arthurielbostonactorportfolio.com/successful_submission.html'); 
                } 
                }
            ?>
            
        </div>
            

        <h3>Email:</h3>
    
        <form class="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
        
            <label for="Name" class="emailtext"></label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name: (ex: John Doe)"/>
            
            <br>
            
            <label for="Email" class="emailtext"></label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email: (ex: JohnDoe@email.com)"/>

            <label for="Message" class="emailtext"></label> 
            <textarea type="text" name="Message" class="message" placeholder="Message: (ex: Here is my email message.)"></textarea> 

            
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
            
        </form>

        <h3>Phone:</h3> <br>
        <p class="paragraph1">+1 ( 610 ) 809-8699</p>
        <h3>Avaliable Locations To Work:</h3>
        <p class="paragraph1">Deleware County, PA
        Philadelphia, PA <br>
        King of Prussia, PA <br>
        New Jersey <br>
        Deleware <br>
        New York City, NY </p>
        </div>
    
    </body>

    <footer>
    &copy; 2024 Arthuriel Boston. All rights reserved.
    </footer>
    
</html>
```

Comment: `die();` will end the script and thats what you have. And thats why nothing else shows after whatever you are deciding to output as a message to the user. see `function problem($error)`.

Comment: So removing die(); excutes my successfulsubmission.html. What I need is the error messages to appear in a div above "<form class="form"...". Apologies, I didn't realize before that all of my code wasn't present before.|

So basically, my error text appears in a div I've contained my php code in: 

<div id ="red error">
My PHP CODE
</div>

$Post form I need to appear here. Input and textarea.